# New window opens with login screen while automating

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing below described issue while automating the application using selenium webdriver:

When I click on a link a new window should pen with the contents of that window, but when I click on the link new window is opening with login screen, what may be the issue, can anyone help me in this regard.

This issue is only with automation (manual click always works), but sometimes works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any link on the page that opens login window? if it is present verify your code is clicking correct link

Comment: Would agree with varaprasd here. There should be no difference between manual vs  selenium as long as they are clicking on same link. One possibility is that the way you login to the application first time might be different manually than via script?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like when a new window opens, all of the session cookies from the previous window are not being transferred. In this situation I would put a try catch block to login again  if the login window appears.